# Rerender list basing on limitTo angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, render

So I have list outputted by `ng-repeat` directive and I have filter `| limitTo: amount` on it.

`amount` variable is changing depending on user screen size. It is changing correctly but list doesn't re-render when variable is updated.

How can I force it to re-render after `amount` viariable change?

HTML

```
<li ng-repeat="n in allCategory | limitTo : amount" order="{{$index+1}}">
```

JS(controller)

```
var screenWidth;

var trackListNumber = function () {
    screenWidth = $window.innerWidth;
    if(screenWidth < 1599) {
        console.log(screenWidth);
        $scope.amount = 18;
    } else {
        $scope.amount = 27;
    }
};

trackListNumber();

angular.element($window).bind('resize', function () {
    trackListNumber();
});
```

**EDIT**

I changed code to

```
var screenWidth;

var trackIconsNumber = $scope.$apply(function() {
    screenWidth = $window.innerWidth;
    if (screenWidth < 1599) {
        console.log(screenWidth);
        $scope.iconsAmount = 18;
    } else {
        $scope.iconsAmount = 9;
    }
});

trackIconsNumber();

angular.element($window).bind('resize', function () {
    trackIconsNumber();
});
```

which cause following error:

> angular.js:14642 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress

Comment: Try `$scope.$apply(trackListNumber)`

Comment: Where should I add it? I tried instead of `trackListNumber();` in resize function and outside which cause following error: `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress`.

Comment: Wrap it like this: `$scope.$apply(function(){  trackListNumber();  });`

Comment: I added EDIT with new code which still doesn't work. Please take a look.

Comment: Wrap the function where you bind to `$window`.

Comment: I'm going to let @ExplosionPills add the answer, since he proposed it here. Not my place to take credit.

Comment: @BT101 I mean instead of `trackIconsNumber()` do `$scope.$apply(trackIconsNumber)`

Comment: It (https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b0b0dcbb7d7b85e2fcbfdead05bdd77b) cause same error as code which I posted above in EDIT. `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress` which is logical because it's pretty much same thing.

Comment: @Brian maybe add your answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [explosion-pills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/454533) said in the comments, you should use $scope.$apply. The implementation should be like so:

**Long Version**

```
angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
  $scope.$apply(function() {
    trackListNumber();
  });
});
```

**Short Version**

```
angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
  $scope.$apply(trackListNumber());
});
```

Comment: AND delete trackIconsNumber(); execution after reload page because it caused another error which I mentioned in edit.

Comment: I mean after reload function should be executed in normal way and on resize with $apply. In other way this doesn't work.